# How to use a factory pattern to get the instance of my Database Client?

Tags: java, thread-safety, singleton, factory-pattern

Below is my Interface -

```
public interface IDBClient {

    public String read(String input);

    public String write(String input);

}
```

This is my Implementation of the Interface -

```
public class DatabaseClient implements IDBClient {

    @Override
    public String read(String input) {

    }

    @Override
    public String write(String input) {

    }
}
```

Now I am thinking to write `Thread Safe Singleton Factory` to get the instance of `DatabaseClient` so that I can call `read` and `write` method accordingly.. So I wrote like this by following the [Initialization On Demand Holder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_on_demand_holder_idiom) idiom, it is still incomplete -

```
public class DatabaseClientFactory {

    public static DatabaseClientFactory getInstance() {
        return ClientHolder.s_instance;
    }

    private static class ClientHolder {

    }
}
```

And I am not sure how to get the instance of `DatabaseClient` correctly in my above Factory? Do I need to add another method `getClient()` to get the instance of `DatabaseClient` and then call like this -

```
IDBClient client = DatabaseClientFactory.getInstance().getClient();
client.read(input); // or client.write(input)
```

Comment: You're talking a lot about design patterns, and that suggests to me something very common and hard to overcome in programming: you are thinking more about your design and less about your needs. Think differently. Worry less about following "design patterns" and more about, "What do I need my code to do?" That's not to say design patterns are irrelevant, but they're tools in the toolbox. In other words, *implement it in a way that works for you and is as simple as possible*. Worry less about the "right" way to organize your code and more about whether your code is simple, correct, and secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shold use [Initialization-on-demand holder idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom), implementing your factory:

```
public class DatabaseClientFactory {
    private DatabaseClientFactory() {}

    private static class LazyHolder {
        private static final DatabaseClient INSTANCE = new DatabaseClient();
    }

    public static DatabaseClient getInstance() {
        return LazyHolder.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

This code doesn't need synchronization because of the contract of the class loader:

- the class loader loads classes when they are first accessed
- all static initialization is executed before anyone can use class
- class loader has its own synchronization that make previous two points guaranteed to be thread safe

Comment: Thank You. Is this a thread safe singleton factory? And also how do we use this factory?

Comment: I've explained thread safeness of this approach. You use it with DatabaseClientFactory getInstance()

Comment: It is giving me a mismatch error somehow.. Cannot convert error.. not sure why.. Any idea?

Comment: @AKIWEB,  that's because getInstance() method declared to return DatabaseClientFactory object but actually returning DatabaseClient object

Answer (score 1):

Here is very a nice [description](http://books.google.com.ua/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA17&lpg=PA17&dq=joshua+bloch+effective+java+singleton+enum&source=bl&ots=yYKoMht6T0&sig=QRAzt8IwfXU6h9DwJFaV77tJdjY&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=LiDRUuvdKsjPsgbgnYDoCA&sqi=2&ved=0CFEQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=joshua%20bloch%20effective%20java%20singleton%20enum&f=false) of correct implementation of singleton from Joshua Bloch's (one of the Java's creators) "Effective Java" book. I would strictly recommend to read at least this chapter.

A few comments:

1. If you want your DatabaseClient to be singleton, you have to move your factory method to this class and make it's constructor private. Otherwise there is no guarantee, that everyone will use your factory and someone won't create the second instance of this class;
2. Even with such approach there is no guarantee, that someone won't use reflection to create new instance of your "singleton";
3. If you decide for some reason to make your DatabaseClient serializable - you'll expose another ability of getting the second instance of "singleton" and will have to apply some additional techniques to avoid this (which are also not always effective).

If you still decide to go this way - you can use one of the approaches suggested by "AgilePro" or "user987339" (with moving that logic to the DatabaseClient). I believe method, described by "user987339" is preferable as it will help to make this initialization really lazy. It's not really the case with approach described by "AgilePro" cause each call to some of the static methods of that class will initialize all static fields.

If you want to get really robust singleton - I suggest you to use enums. So your DatabaseClient will look like:

```
public enum DatabaseClient {

    INSTANCE;

    DatabaseClient() {
    }

    public String read(String input) {
    }

    public String write(String input) {
    }
}
```

And its usage:

```
final DatabaseClient databaseClient = DatabaseClient.INSTANCE;
```

P.S. One more note related to all approaches: if you get some exception during initialization of DatabaseClient - you'll get "java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError" which won't let you to initialize this class any longer (for all further calls to this class you'll get "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError").

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need:

```
public class DatabaseClientFactory {
    private static final DatabaseClient mySingleton = new DatabaseClient();

    public static IDBClient getInstance() {
        return mySingleton;
    }
}
```

Note the `private static final` member that holds the singleton instance.  Declaring it `final` prevents you fromwriting code that might create another instance.  In this case we construct as static initialization time which happens before any thread can possibly access it, but you could construct with lazy initialization at run time if you desired.  In this latter case you would need to make the method synchronized, which is a bit more overhead.

I made the factory method return the interface, but it could if you wish be declared to return the concrete class instead.  If your concrete class has some additional methods beyond the interface you may want to do the latter.

Access it like this

```
IDBClient client = DatabaseClientFactory.getInstance();
```

It is thread safe because the variable that holds the singleton object is initialized at static initialization time, before any thread can access it.  Since it is never changed after that, there is no possibility of a race condition.

This approach is simpler than that other answer because this involves only two classes, which is all you need: the factory class and the client class.  One of the other answers requires three classes.  This is a very small difference, since an extra class is a very small overhead, but if you believe that code should remain as simple as possible for maintenance reasons, then using three classes when two would do is a waste.

Comment: It is thread safe in the sense that there will be one instance of the object, and all threads will use that one instance.   You would need the singleton object implementation to be threadsafe of course.